# Is there any concept of "troubling" G-d?

Tags: sources-mekorot, theology

Is there any idea mentioned on Judaism of not wanting to "trouble" G-d with something too trivial? Obviously, G-d is infinite, and it's no more trouble for Him to do a thousand things than it is to do one, but nevertheless, is there any mention of this in the sources?

Inspired by a recent comment conversation.

Comment: A good place to start looking is the meforshim to the first page of Sotah "וקשין לזווגן כקריעת ים סוף".

Comment: According to the Artscroll Gemora footnote 40, She'arim Metzuyanim BaHalacha discuses this.

Comment: @Michoel Where in the Shearim Metzuyanim Bahalachah? Does Artscroll give the exact source?

Comment: @ba It doesn't but I believe I have seen Shearim Metzuyanim Bahalachah on the seder of shas. The only one that comes up on HebrewBooks is the one on Kitzur Shulchan Aruch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Mabit (R' Moshe m'Trani) discusses this issue in the first chapter of his *sefer*, *Beis Elokim*. He writes that it is improper to pray for unnecessary things - "כי הוא מטריח את קונו ללא צורך" - "for he unnecessarily troubles his Master" - a concept found in the Talmud ([*Taanis* 24a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=10&daf=24&format=pdf)). The Mabit discusses this at length, but his basic point is that the acceptance of prayer is a supernatural event, and God "dislikes" unnecessarily disturbing the natural order that He created.